# How to call a C++ exported function from C#, in another process?

Tags: c#, c++, function, process, call

I haven't found anything useful related to this problem after some serious google lurking, so I'll ask it here.

I have a program that's made in C# that injects a DLL into another process, fairly trivial.  It Calls CreateRemoteThread and LoadLibrary from kernel32.dll with [DllImport].

My DLL once loaded then waits for authentication from the C# program, due to security reasons, I can't have this data transferred using sockets.  So I have my DLL export a function that's planned to be called from the C# program with authentication data.

The exported function takes two arguments, it is as follows :

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DoStuff( const char* ccString1, const char* ccString2 ){

    // Do stuff

}
```

Since as the DLL isn't in the same address space as the C# program, I can't use [DllImport] to get and the call the exported function.

My second idea was to use CreateRemoteThread to call the function, though that can only be passed 1 argument whereas I need two, it'd also be difficult because I'd need to call the return of GetProcAddress, I can't simply call by exported function directly.

So, how would I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use any IPC method or just socket?

Comment: The ability to intercept the data transferred between the two programs is something that I would like to avoid.  I have a lot of experience with Sockets and I knew that clients could use programs as simple as Wireshark to log packets sent from my C# application to my C++ DLL, though in all honesty, I haven't really worked with other IPC methods and I don't know how well they'd work for me.

Answer (score 0):

[DllImport] is the same as GetProcAddress. C# does not load the DLL until the first call, so the .NET can do the security checks before calling the DLL.

---

If you don't trust the DLL at all, then it's better to split de C# program in two. One program  connected via Remoting/WCF/IPC to the second one, and the second one connects to the C DLL via DllImport. This solution is typically used when you don't trust C DLL stability or memory allocation because the second program (the one that call de C DLL) can be restarted without restarting the main program. Example of this pattern: some windows drivers (with the exception that they don't use C# at this time).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Non-persisted memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) to exchange data between the application and the DLL.